# Strange javascript chrome issue with menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Visit the following site in chrom and teh first time the page loads the top nav displays on two lines, if you click to another page then home again the top nav displays correctly (all on one line), why is this?

I thinkit may be javascript related but can't get to the bottom of it.

Any ideas?

http://berrisford.gumpshen.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how it does this, but if you inspect the code around your little house image, in some cases it has a style of 16.7px padding, left and right, and other times 19.5px.

Seriously, fractional pixels?

Figure out why it generating 2 different styles (there are other differences in the source of the page) and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Think I got it. There is an image that is inserted in place of the "Home" link in the menu, first page load chrome wasn't picking up the correct image width I think. I pu ta set width on the image and bingo it worked.